# upper bound for the number of integer solutions of a special equation

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

we know that the number of integer solutions for the following equation with integers $m, r$:

$\begin{equation}
z_1 + \cdots + z_m = 2m, \quad 1 \leq z_i \leq r
\end{equation}$

is $N = \binom{2m-1}{m-1} - \binom{m}{1} \binom{2m-r-1}{m-1} + \binom{m}{2} \binom{2m-2r-1}{m-1} - \binom{m}{3} \binom{2m-3r-1}{m-1}+ \binom{m}{4} \binom{2m-4r-1}{m-1}- \cdots$

I am interesting in the asymptotic behavior of $N$ when $m$ goes to infinity. My first try is to derive a upper bound for $N$, but I do not know how to do that. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: You might be interested in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018957/number-of-solutions-to-x-1x-2-x-m-n?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks, but this does not investigate the asymptotic behavior